# How to access WebSession from AbstractRequestCycleListener in wicket 6.4?

Tags: java, wicket

I wrote my own `RequestCycleListener` to log some info. How can I access wicket `WebSession` object from this class?

```
public class MyRequestCycleListener extends AbstractRequestCycleListener {
    @Override
    public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle) {
        super.onBeginRequest(cycle);

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndRequest(RequestCycle cycle) {
        super.onEndRequest(cycle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere in your code, you should be able to access the current session by:

```
WebSession session = WebSession.get();
```